# Windows script to delete everything but image file extensions

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to create a script on Windows 7 to delete everything in a directory that is not a picture.
So

```
    for all files in directory X

    if file y does not have extension in (.png, .gif, .jpeg)

    delete y

    end
```

that's it

how can I find or create such a script

mind you, some pictures are important, so this script has to work correctly :) I don't think I should be experimenting here, and even if I tested my own script on a small directory with experimental files, I am not confident that I should try it.

I have this code as suggested:

```
::extensions are delimited with space // filename is del_stuff.bat

set "extensions_list=.png .gif .jpeg .bmp .jpg "
pushd "C:\Users\denman\Desktop\xxx\"
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b ^|findstr /i /e /v "%extensions_list%" ') do (
        echo del /q /f "%%~f" 
)
popd
```

But I get this error:

[image]

Comment: If you already have your script, feel free to share it. Also, never assume a program will work 100% with no issues. Actually, always assume an ultimate failure, you will be less disappointed later. :)

Comment: As far as PowerShell goes Remove-Item is the cmdlet that you want, and the genius of it is that there is a -WhatIf switch that will simply output to the screen what would happen instead of actually deleting anything so it is completely safe to use so long as you use the -WhatIf switch. Give it a try and come on back if you run into trouble. I'm sure we can help if you get errors and need some guidance.

Comment: Questions should include code you've tried and the problems you've encountered. Questions asking us to write a script for you are off-topic.

Comment: Fyi there are more picture extension other than .png .gif .jpeg. You also have .jpg .bmp and obviously a host of other so tread carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
::extensions are delimited with space
set "extensions_list=.png .gif .jpeg "
pushd "C:\Directory_with_pictures" && (
   for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d ^|findstr /i /e /v "%extensions_list%" ') do (
        echo del /q /f "%%~f"
   )
  popd
)
```

The 'echo'  is to verify the result .remove the echo to activate deletion.And change `"C:\Directory_with_pictures"` with the actual path.

**EDIT** testing the script:

```
@echo off

md test_dir>nul 2>&1
echo #>test_dir\t1.png
echo #>test_dir\t1.txt
echo #>test_dir\t1.tst
echo #>test_dir\t1.jpg
echo #>test_dir\t1.gif

echo #>test_dir\t2.png
echo #>test_dir\t2.txt
echo #>test_dir\t2.tst
echo #>test_dir\t2.jpg
echo #>test_dir\t2.gif

echo -- before deleting--
dir /b .\test_dir\*
echo(
echo(

::extensions are delimited with space
set "extensions_list=.png .gif .jpeg .jpg"


pushd "test_dir"
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b ^|findstr /i /e /v "%extensions_list%" ') do (
        del /q /f "%%~f"
)
popd

echo -- after deleting --
dir /b .\test_dir\*
```

Output:

```
-- before deleting--
t1.gif
t1.jpg
t1.png
t1.tst
t1.txt
t2.gif
t2.jpg
t2.png
t2.tst
t2.txt


-- after deleting --
t1.gif
t1.jpg
t1.png
t2.gif
t2.jpg
t2.png
```

Comment: this didn't seem to work, I put a .txt file and a .png file in a directory, neither were deleted :/

Comment: @AlexMills - check my edit.Script works as expected.Just added `/q /f` switches to del command..

Comment: Make sure that you type the correct folder name for the `pushd` command.  Add `pause` as the last line so that you can read the screen too.

Comment: Small suggestion to add '/c:' in findstr line.  Change to "findstr /i /e /v /c:"%extensions_list%", so it doesn't ignore the leading dot.

Comment: @RyanBemrose - If I use `/C:` option the spaces would not be taken as delimiters and findstr will look for whole string to exclude.

Comment: @npocmaka My bad, you're correct.  Please ignore me.  :)

Comment: still getting an error, that I posted in the original quesiton

Comment: @AlexMills - try to run this from command prompt , but not from the git console.

Comment: yes, it seems to find the right files to delete, and prints them out after the command is run, but it does not actually remove them from the directory...hmmmmm

Comment: AHHH, ok, I removed the echo from the del line, and it worked, thank you Sir! :)

Answer (score 3):

Using Powershell, you can get the list of files you need with something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem | where {!$_.PsIsContainer -and !(@(".png",".gif",".jpeg") -contains $_.Extension) }
```

I left the [Delete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176938.aspx) command to you, make sure the list returns correct results before you do it.

Comment: Well if we're going to just feed him an answer why not `GCI 'C:\Path\To\Files\*' -Include '*.png','*.gif','*.jpeg'` and let the provider filter for him? It's much faster if you have a lot of files.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: To show the true power of Powershell! Seriously though, my powershell is rusty, but this is how I've been doing it in one of my scripts a while ago. The above is mostly showcasing use of `.PsIsContainer`. Also feel free to post yours as an answer. We aren't on codegolf, but I will upvote it as the shortest solution so far. :)

Comment: Now that I think of it, my suggestion does the exact opposite of what he wants. the `-Include` should be `-Exclude`. Aside from that it doesn't return directories, so you don't even need to check for .PSIsContainer, and can pipe directly into Remove-Item.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: Yeah, I got your point. IMHO, worth making an answer out of it.